# jquery ui autocomplete search in xml file

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui, search, autocomplete

I add a search input with autocomplete to parse an xml file.

I have some difficulties to understand how it works exactly.

my code:

```
var myArr = [];

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml", 
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml,
    complete: setupAC,
    failure: function(data) {
    alert("XML File could not be found");
    }
});

function parseXml(xml) {

    $(xml).find("element").each(function() {    

        title = $(this).text();
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        category = $(this).attr("category");
        urlimage = $(this).find('urlimage').attr("src");
        urlpageautocomplete = $(this).find('urlpage').attr("url");
        imageautocomplete = "image-autocomplete";
        titleautocomplete = "title-autocomplete";
        categoryautocomplete = "category-autocomplete";
        linkurl = "link-auto";
        var quotes = "'";

        value = "<a class="+linkurl+" href="+ urlpageautocomplete +" onclick=gestionClic(compteur"+id+");><div class=" + imageautocomplete + "><img src='" + urlimage + "'/ ></div>" + "<div class=" + titleautocomplete + ">"+title +"</div><div class=" + categoryautocomplete + ">"+ category+"</div></a>";  
    myArr.push(value);      
    })

}


function setupAC() {
$( "input#search" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      source: myArr,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
         $('input#search').focus();
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "input#search" ).val( ui.item.value );
        return false;
      }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append(item.value)
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
}
```

Here an xml example

```
<element id="13" size="normal" category="blog">
        <tag>iphone dock apple printing 3d</icon>
        <icon class="icon-pencil"></icon>
        <urlpage url="/portfolio/dock.html"></urlpage>
        <urlimage src='./Post thumbnail images/formlabs.jpg'></urlimage>
        <date date="12 Apr"></date>
        <title>Formlabs 3D printer</title>
</element>
```

In my example, I just want to search in xml : tag, title and category.

And I want to display in result: urlimage, title and category.

Currently, my script search in every field of the xml file but display the correct results...
How can I search just in some xml field?

I try to make a fiddle but it don't works on it: http://jsfiddle.net/UaEsp/2/

Sorry for my English, I'm french.

Comment: Are you making the AJAX request from the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I ran into an issue accessing the xml file. Hope you are working on the same server (http://freakyshape.com/). I have created a new form from your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/AAa88/).

I have extracted a method to create object with desired properties from the xml nodes. These items are pushed into the array which is further assigned as source for autocomplete.

`autocomplete` searches in `value` property of search items so I have put the following line `ret.value=title + " " + category;` which did the trick to restrict search to specific fields in xml.

```
var SearchItem = function (title, id, category, urlimage, urlpageautocomplete) {
        var ret = new Object();
        ret.value=title + " " + category;/*NEED THIS TO SEARCH*/
        ret.lable=title;/*NEED THIS TO DISPLAY IN SEARCH BOX*/
        ret.title = title;
        ret.id = id;
        ret.category = category;
        ret.urlimage = urlimage;
        ret.urlpageautocomplete = urlpageautocomplete;
        ret.imageautocomplete = "image-autocomplete";
        ret.titleautocomplete = "title-autocomplete";
        ret.categoryautocomplete = "category-autocomplete";
        ret.linkurl = "link-auto";
            ret.renderHtml= "<a class=" + ret.linkurl + " href=" 
                + ret.urlpageautocomplete 
                + " onclick=gestionClic(compteur" + ret.id + ");><div class=" 
                + ret.imageautocomplete + "><img src='" + ret.urlimage 
                + "'/ ></div>" + "<div class=" + ret.titleautocomplete + ">" 
                + ret.title + "</div><div class=" + ret.categoryautocomplete 
                + ">" + ret.category + "</div></a>";
        return ret;
    }
```

So your `parseXml` function is now like this:

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("element").each(function () {
        title = $(this).text();
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        category = $(this).attr("category");
        urlimage = $(this).find('urlimage').attr("src");
        urlpageautocomplete = $(this).find('urlpage').attr("url");

        $("#debug").append($("<div/>").text(title));
        myArr.push(new SearchItem(title, id, category, 
                              urlimage, urlpageautocomplete));
    });
}
```

The `_renderItem` is changed to pick value from `renderHtml` property of the search item.

Comment: Thank you for the answere. It works great! With this autocomplete function I really have some difficulties. FOr example, I want to add "no result message" if nothing is found. But I didn't success. And I also don't know how to display the loading gif during the search...

Comment: There is something that I really don't understand. It's again about the node to search and the label that is display inside the input box. It's not working when I search in several nodes in my xml file... Your example not work correctly

Comment: well if you can explain how its not working with several nodes and provide relevant xml data I will look into it.

Comment: Finally, like this it works (and without the select option for autocomplete) : `ret.value=title ;
  ret.label=title + " " + category + " " + tag;` However, the value that is selected and put in the input box have a lot's of blank spaces before. So, you can't see the value inside the input box without go at right with keybord right key... I don't know where it comes from. Look at here : http://freakyshape.com/

Comment: When I select an element in the result search menu, the input receive the correct value but add a lot's of tab (white space) before the input value. I really don't understand where it comes from...

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks crappy in IE10-9 and Chrome. The payout is weird but there is no white space before text displayed in search box. I think you need to include `migrate` plugin for jquery

Comment: Finally I solve my problem with this : `titleinput = ui.item.value;
              ui.item.value= $.trim(titleinput);` it was tabulation space before text. It's not present in my xml file. I read it's a knew problem sometimes with xml data file...